# Comparing Primary Key Constraints Between Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The query below compares primary keys between two databases. It identifies all primary key constraints in one database but not the other. When I run the query some of the constraint names appear to be system generated (i.e. `PK__afm_scmpref__2D27B809` or `PK__projfund__E34271EE251CF998`) Since these are system generated I can't compare them across databases. Is there some way around this problem?

Many Thanks,

Here is my code:

```
SELECT src.table_name AS src_table,
   src.constraint_name AS scr_constraint_name,
   src.column_name AS src_column_name,
   src.ordinal_position AS src_ordinal_position,
   tgt.table_name AS tgt_table_name ,
   tgt.constraint_name AS tgt_constraint_name,
   tgt.column_name AS tgt_column_name,
   tgt.ordinal_position AS tgt_ordinal_position
from db_comp_src_primary_keys src
   FULL OUTER JOIN
db_comp_tgt_primary_keys tgt ON
    src.table_name = tgt.table_name
    AND src.constraint_name = tgt.constraint_name

 WHERE (   (src.constraint_name IS NULL AND tgt.constraint_name IS NOT NULL)
    OR (src.constraint_name IS NOT NULL AND tgt.constraint_name IS NULL))
 AND (   (           tgt.table_name IS NULL
            AND src.table_name IS NOT NULL
            AND src.constraint_name IS NOT NULL
            AND src.table_name IN
                   (SELECT table_name
                      FROM [HQ-193-STOCK-DBO].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables))
        OR (    src.table_name IS NULL
            AND tgt.table_name IS NOT NULL
            AND tgt.constraint_name IS NOT NULL
            AND tgt.table_name IN
                   (SELECT table_name
                      FROM [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables)))
```

Comment: You need to compare the column name-sets of the PKs, not the PK names themselves.

Comment: What are the `db_comp_src_primary_keys` and `db_comp_tgt_primary_keys` tables/views?  Can you provide a definition?

Comment: Do the two databases have the same schema, other than the primary keys? Do the tables have the same name? Otherwise, what do you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this which bases the check on whether all the columns of one primary key are the same as the other primary key

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    QUOTENAME(t1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME) [Source],
    QUOTENAME(t2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t2.CONSTRAINT_NAME) [Target],
    CASE WHEN t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME  IS NULL OR t2.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NULL THEN 'DISCREPANCY'
         WHEN t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> t2.CONSTRAINT_NAME THEN 'NAME MISMATCH'
         ELSE 'COMPLETE MATCH' END [Status]
FROM (
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    JOIN msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE C
      ON C.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
     AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE PK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) t1
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    JOIN msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE C
      ON C.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
     AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE PK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) t2 ON t2.TABLE_NAME = t1.TABLE_NAME
    AND t2.COLUMN_NAME = t1.COLUMN_NAME
```